# Making asynchronous requests using Unirest returns ZipException: Not in GZIP format

Tags: java, json, encoding, gzip, unirest

I want to make asynchronous requests to my server using [Unirest](http://unirest.io/).

This is my test code:

```
public void unirestTest() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Unirest.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
                .header(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON.toString())
                .asJsonAsync(new Callback<JsonNode>() {
                                 public void failed(UnirestException e) {
                                     e.printStackTrace();
                                 }

                                 public void completed(HttpResponse<JsonNode> response) {
                                     System.out.println("OK");
                                 }

                                 public void cancelled() {
                                     System.out.println("Request has been canceled.");
                                 }
                             }
                ).get();
    }
```

This is what I get in the console:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:64120', transport: 'socket'
02:09:15.263 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec - [exchange: 1] start execution
02:09:15.294 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: default
02:09:15.341 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
02:09:15.341 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient - [exchange: 1] Request connection for {s}->https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com:443
02:09:15.356 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 20; total allocated: 0 of 200]
02:09:16.394 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: http-outgoing-0][route: {s}->https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 20; total allocated: 1 of 200]
02:09:16.394 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient - [exchange: 1] Connection allocated: CPoolProxy{http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE]}
02:09:16.394 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl - http-outgoing-0 192.168.189.147:64147<->104.31.86.157:443[ACTIVE][r:]: Set attribute http.nio.exchange-handler
02:09:16.394 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl - http-outgoing-0 192.168.189.147:64147<->104.31.86.157:443[ACTIVE][rw:]: Event set [w]
02:09:16.394 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl - http-outgoing-0 192.168.189.147:64147<->104.31.86.157:443[ACTIVE][rw:]: Set timeout 0
02:09:16.394 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch - http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE]: Connected
02:09:16.394 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl - http-outgoing-0 192.168.189.147:64147<->104.31.86.157:443[ACTIVE][rw:]: Set attribute http.nio.http-exchange-state
02:09:16.394 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient - Start connection routing
02:09:16.552 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl - http-outgoing-0 Upgrade session 192.168.189.147:64147<->104.31.86.157:443[ACTIVE][rw:][ACTIVE][rw][NEED_UNWRAP][0][0][235][0]
02:09:16.553 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec - Connection route established
02:09:16.553 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec - [exchange: 1] Attempt 1 to execute request
02:09:16.553 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
02:09:16.554 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
02:09:16.554 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl - http-outgoing-0 192.168.189.147:64147<->104.31.86.157:443[ACTIVE][rw:][ACTIVE][rw][NEED_UNWRAP][0][0][235][0]: Set timeout 60000
02:09:16.554 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> GET /posts/1 HTTP/1.1
02:09:16.554 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> accept-encoding: gzip
02:09:16.555 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
02:09:16.555 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> user-agent: unirest-java/1.3.11
02:09:16.555 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
02:09:16.555 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
02:09:16.556 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl - http-outgoing-0 192.168.189.147:64147<->104.31.86.157:443[ACTIVE][rw:][ACTIVE][rw][NEED_UNWRAP][0][0][235][0]: Event set [w]
02:09:16.556 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec - [exchange: 1] Request completed
02:09:16.659 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl - http-outgoing-0 192.168.189.147:64147<->104.31.86.157:443[ACTIVE][rw:w][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][217][0]: 188 bytes written
02:09:16.659 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "GET /posts/1 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.659 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "accept-encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.659 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.659 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "user-agent: unirest-java/1.3.11[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.659 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.659 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.659 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.660 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch - http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE] Request ready
02:09:16.660 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl - http-outgoing-0 192.168.189.147:64147<->104.31.86.157:443[ACTIVE][r:w][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0][0]: Event cleared [w]
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl - http-outgoing-0 192.168.189.147:64147<->104.31.86.157:443[ACTIVE][r:r][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0][0]: 887 bytes read
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Thu, 06 Apr 2017 00:09:07 GMT[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dfa98af248364fb21c08736140224a1321491437347; expires=Fri, 06-Apr-18 00:09:07 GMT; path=/; domain=.typicode.com; HttpOnly[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "X-Powered-By: Express[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Vary: Accept-Encoding[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Cache-Control: public, max-age=14400[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Pragma: no-cache[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Expires: Thu, 06 Apr 2017 04:09:07 GMT[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Etag: W/"124-yiKdLzqO5gfBrJFrcdJ8Yq0LGnU"[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Via: 1.1 vegur[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "CF-Cache-Status: HIT[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Server: cloudflare-nginx[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "CF-RAY: 34b0843afbaf15dd-FRA[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "ca[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x1f][0xffffff8b][0x8][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x3]U[0xffffff8f]Kj[0x4]A[0xc]C[0xfffffff7]s[\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Q[0xffffffeb]l[0xffffffb2][0xffffff9d][0x1b][0xffffffe4][0xe][0xffffffbd]q\[\n]"
02:09:16.716 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "c[0xffffffe8][0xfffffffa][0xffffff8c][0xffffffcb][0x1e]&[0xffffff84][0xffffffdc]=tC[0x8][0x1]#$[0xffffff90][0x1f][0xffffffe8][0xffffffeb][0x2][0xffffff94]\[0xfffffff4][0xffffffb7]Z[0xffffffae]x}9[0xffffffa2][0xfffffffd][0xffffffd9][0xffffffb0][0xffffffd8]Y[0xffffffae](+{@2[0xfffffff0]!J'[0xffffff9c][0xffffff93][0xfffffffb].[0xffffff81][0xffffffe9][0xffffffe3]a[0xffffff95]=0T[0xffffff85]*a[0xffffffe0]S9#[0xffffffdd]0f[0xffffffd8]8[0xffffffca][0xffffffce][0x1b]{[0xffffffa5][[0xffffff94][0x13][0xfffffffc]>[0xffffffea][0xffffffe7][0xffffffc1][0xffffffbd][0xffffffa7][0x9][0x18]X[0xffffffb9][0xffffffd4][0xffffffa6][0xffffffc5][0xffffffd6][0x1d][0xffffff9c][0xffffff9a]Kz[0x15]BG_[0xffffffbc]g[0xfffffff6]H[0x7][0xffffff9f][0xffffff93][0xffffffd5][0xffffffe2]|[0xffffffd3]l[[0xffffffff][0xffffff87]G[0x1b];W[0xffffff98][0x10][0x19][0xffffffc7][0xffffffdd]S[0x16]b[0xffffff84][0xffffffb4][0xffffffad][0xfffffff7][0xffffffb1][0xffffffc2][0xffffffb3][0xffffffc1]y([0xffffffd7]9[0xffffff89][\r][0xffffffe7]:g[0x3][0x1f][0xffffffec][0xffffffc6][0xffffff80][0xffffffb8][0xffffffde],[0xffffffa8]1[0xffffffca][0xffffffe5][0xfffffffb][0x7][0x15][0xffffffc6][0xffffff93][0xffffffe8]$[0x1][0x0][0x0][\r][\n]"
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "0[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Date: Thu, 06 Apr 2017 00:09:07 GMT
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Connection: keep-alive
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dfa98af248364fb21c08736140224a1321491437347; expires=Fri, 06-Apr-18 00:09:07 GMT; path=/; domain=.typicode.com; HttpOnly
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << X-Powered-By: Express
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Vary: Accept-Encoding
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Cache-Control: public, max-age=14400
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Pragma: no-cache
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Expires: Thu, 06 Apr 2017 04:09:07 GMT
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Etag: W/"124-yiKdLzqO5gfBrJFrcdJ8Yq0LGnU"
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Via: 1.1 vegur
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << CF-Cache-Status: HIT
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Server: cloudflare-nginx
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << CF-RAY: 34b0843afbaf15dd-FRA
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Encoding: gzip
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch - http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE(213)] Response received
02:09:16.731 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec - [exchange: 1] Response received HTTP/1.1 200 OK
02:09:16.809 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies - Cookie accepted [__cfduid="dfa98af248364fb21c08736140224a1321491437347", version:0, domain:typicode.com, path:/, expiry:Fri Apr 06 02:09:07 CEST 2018]
02:09:16.809 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch - http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE(213)] Input ready
02:09:16.809 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec - [exchange: 1] Consume content
02:09:16.809 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl - http-outgoing-0 192.168.189.147:64147<->104.31.86.157:443[ACTIVE][r:r][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0][0]: 0 bytes read
02:09:16.809 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl - http-outgoing-0 192.168.189.147:64147<->104.31.86.157:443[ACTIVE][r:r][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0][0]: 0 bytes read
02:09:16.809 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl - http-outgoing-0 192.168.189.147:64147<->104.31.86.157:443[ACTIVE][r:r][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0][0]: 0 bytes read
02:09:16.809 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient - [exchange: 1] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
02:09:16.809 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec - [exchange: 1] Response processed
02:09:16.809 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient - [exchange: 1] releasing connection
02:09:16.809 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl - http-outgoing-0 192.168.189.147:64147<->104.31.86.157:443[ACTIVE][r:r][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0][0]: Remove attribute http.nio.exchange-handler
02:09:16.809 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager - Releasing connection: [id: http-outgoing-0][route: {s}->https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 20; total allocated: 1 of 200]
02:09:16.809 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection [id: http-outgoing-0][route: {s}->https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com:443] can be kept alive indefinitely
02:09:16.809 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl - http-outgoing-0 192.168.189.147:64147<->104.31.86.157:443[ACTIVE][r:r][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0][0]: Set timeout 0
02:09:16.809 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: http-outgoing-0][route: {s}->https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com:443][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 20; total allocated: 1 of 200]
02:09:20.463 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing expired connections
02:09:20.478 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing expired connections
02:09:22.092 [Thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing connections idle longer than 30 SECONDS
02:09:22.092 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing connections idle longer than 30 SECONDS
02:09:22.092 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch - http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE] Exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse.<init>(HttpResponse.java:106)
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper$1.completed(HttpClientHelper.java:82)
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper$1.completed(HttpClientHelper.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.responseCompleted(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.processResponse(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.inputReady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:326)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalRequestExecutor.inputReady(InternalRequestExecutor.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse.<init>(HttpResponse.java:89)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:165)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:79)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:91)
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse.<init>(HttpResponse.java:85)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
02:09:22.092 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl - http-outgoing-0 192.168.189.147:64147<->104.31.86.157:443[ACTIVE][r:r][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0][0]: Shutdown
02:09:22.092 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch - http-outgoing-0 [CLOSED]: Disconnected

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format

    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse.<init>(HttpResponse.java:106)
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper$2.get(HttpClientHelper.java:120)
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper$2.get(HttpClientHelper.java:104)
    at SensorHealthCheckerTest.unirestTest(SensorHealthCheckerTest.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse.<init>(HttpResponse.java:89)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:165)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:79)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:91)
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse.<init>(HttpResponse.java:85)
    ... 25 more

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:64120', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code -1
```

I expect this request to be executed without any errors. I noticed that it works with some servers like https://api.ipify.org?format=json but it's not working with mine.

The error says that the response is not in GZIP format. I don't know how to react to this. Should I change somehow expected format in Unirest or add some headers, so the server returns the response in GZIP format? What should I do?

I tried to add header `Accept-encoding: gzip` to the request but without success.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, I didn't find the solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you could try see if it could work for you.
I suppose you are receiving response in GZIP format and you could get raw body of the response as `InputStream`. I am not sure how you'd do that for GZIP but at least this hopefuly could shed some light.

```
MultipartBody request = Unirest.post("url");
Future<HttpResponse<String>> response = request.asStringAsync(new 
Callback<String>() {

            @Override
            public void failed(UnirestException e) {
               //
            }

            @Override
            public void completed(HttpResponse<String> response) {
                int code = response.getStatus();
                //how about converting the rawbody to GZIP?
                InputStream fileBody = response.getRawBody();
            }

            @Override
            public void cancelled() {
                //
            }

        });
```